# C# XmlDocument modifies data when you load it?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I'm recieving a Base64 encoded saml assertion from a 3rd party (its signed xml). I cant verify the signature. After close inspection, it appears that when i read in the SAML xml that XmlDocument changes the data. See this code:

```
string rawXml = Util.DecodeBase64(SAMLResponse);
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawXml);
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();

s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
s.Flush();
s.Position = 0;
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xml.Load(s);


MemoryStream s2 = new MemoryStream();
xml.Save(s2);
s2.Position = 0;
byte[] b2 = new byte[s2.Length];
s2.Read(b2, 0, b2.Length);
```

b has a length of 6410 bytes where b2 has a length of 6416 further when i add

```
int diffcount = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < b2.Length; x++)
{
    if(x > b.Length-1 || b[x]!=b2[x])
    diffcount++;
}
```

difffcount turns out to be 5572

any ideas how i can get xmldocument to preserve the byte values?
Thanks

Comment: Using a real diff mechanism, what are the exact changes? :-) With just 6 bytes I'd imagine it'd be a change in the particular encoding used to represent an XML-unsafe construct (if the diff count was ~6410 I'd imagine the addition of Unicode control data).

Comment: yes you are correct... i did some more looking and discovered that Elements that are self closing that do NOT have a space after an attribute closing quote and the /> get a space added by XmlDocument

Comment: Is there a way to get XmlDocument to preserve whitespace. It doesnt seem like setting preservewhitespace to true does much in this case

Answer (score 0):

Same predicament here: csharp, validating incoming SAML signed xml, received as base64 encoded xml string - but the xml document created from it would output a handful of bytes more. It turned out that these were not only the extra spaces for self-closing elements inserted in .net output, but also the use of "\r\n" for linefeeds where the original input string had only "\n".

So now I test the input string for these features (self-closing element without preceeding space? only "\n" for linefeeds?) and then throughout the process of validating the signed xml (digest value, signature) I make sure that any intermediate xml document will be created from a string that is prepared in the same way by [xmlString].Replace(" />", "/>") and/or [xmlString].Replace("\r\n", "\n"). This does make a difference, so apparently the .net xml document internally does stick to the original input string it was created with.

There is however one exception to this: there's also the occassion where I receive an xml string without the extra spaces for self-closing elements but with the full "\r\n" linefeed sequence. Following my procedure mentioned above however - [xmlString].Replace(" />", "/>") - I cannot replicate the SignatureValue and DigestValue in the xml; however, if in this situation I also replace the linefeed sequence - [xmlString].Replace("\r\n", "\n") - I get to the correct values. Apparently in this situation the SignatureValue and DigestValue are first computed with only "\n" as linefeed, and then - when the xml document was Base64 encoded - a string containing "\r\n" was used.

For validating purposes, in the end only the difference in linefeed sequences seem to matter, because the extra spaces for self-closing elements will disappear after canonicalization (when explicit closing tags are introduced) which usually preceeds the computation of DigestValue and SignatureValue.